# @media works on css. Is there something for html?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The @media works in the css section of an html file. However, I want a centered < table > with one column if the screen is below 600px wide or with 2 columns if it is greater than 600px.

The exact same stuff will be in the table but arranged differently. Elements in the table (select boxes) will have the same id in both layouts.

Is there any way of doing this?

So in 600px or less I want:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But in greater than 600px I want:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff 1</td>
        <td>Stuff 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff 3</td>
        <td>Stuff 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Media queries go in the CSS file.

Comment: @APAD1 - you have hit the nail on the head. I want a different table (html code) depending on the width of the device. media only works on css. That is the problem. I will edit to make it clearer.

Comment: The easiest (but not nicest) way is to have both blocks - two tables - in the markup and switch their `display: none/block` in the CSS media queries. Or you can use `Javascript` to merge/split rows.

Comment: You mean you want the table to be styled differently depending on the width? Then you need to add media queries to your CSS.

Comment: @MelanciaUK surely that will cause problems with the same id being in an html file?

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/rv3uuojw/)?

Comment: @Rewind, yes that's one of the problems you would face.

Comment: @APAD1 With the edited code above (showing the tables) how would I do it?

Comment: [Responsive design: Changing markup with media queries or jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258335/responsive-design-changing-markup-with-media-queries-or-jquery)

Comment: Seems to me like a table is the wrong approach here anyway. Tables are for data that have a row/column relationship. This apparently doesn't, and the OP should be using a responsive grid instead.

Comment: @APAD1 - The stuff you are doing seems to be what I am after, but I do not understand what is making it work. Also, you have a table in a table. I have read mobiles do not like that.

Comment: @isherwood I have no idea what a responsive grid is. Do you have a link?

Comment: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid, http://www.gumbyframework.com/docs/grid/#!/basic-grid. They all use the same basic concepts.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Responsive design with divs looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this and only use a single table since they will have the same content.

```css
table, tr, td {
    display:block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
    table {
        display:table;
    }
    tr {
        display:table-row;
    }
    td {
        display:table-cell;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff 1</td>
        <td>Stuff 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff 3</td>
        <td>Stuff 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Responsive grid approach:**

As Isherwood stated in his comment:

> Seems to me like a table is the wrong approach here anyway. Tables are for data that have a row/column relationship. This apparently doesn't, and the OP should be using a responsive grid instead. –  isherwood

This is probably best done without tables.

```css
div {box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;}

@media only screen and (min-width:600px) {
   .half {
       float: left;
       margin: 0;
       width: 50%;
   }
   .row:after {
     content:"";
     display:table;
     clear:both;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="half">Stuff 1</div>
        <div class="half">Stuff 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="half">Stuff 3</div>
        <div class="half">Stuff 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It sets the base display property of the table elements to "block" which will put each element on a separate line with a default width of 100%. In screens that have a minimum width of 600px  (`@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)`) the display property is reset to their correct defaults which present the elements in their original table format.

Comment: Edited: Added a basic responsive grid approach to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think the responsive design bit looks best. I will use that.

Comment: can I ask what is, and why I need '.row:after'?

Comment: It is called a "clearfix". What it does is insert a pseudo element into the `.row` class at the very end "after" all of its children elements. Since this element is clearing all previous floated elements it will make the the elements below `.row` respect the layout and not allow all of the floated elements to overlap. In this case you can get by without it and just use `.row {clear: both;}`. http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/